# How to remove react-cookie-consent bar when cookie exist?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, react-cookie-consent

I use reactjs and nodejs. I create an api url which create my `jsonwebtoken`

```
const createToken = (id) =>{
  return jwt.sign({id},123)
}

module.exports.mandatoryTokens = async (req,res) =>{
  try{
    const token = createToken(new Date())
    res.cookie('force',token, {httpOnly : true})
    res.status(200).send('ok')
  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(200).send(err)
  }
}
```

this is my reactjs side

```
const App = () => {

  const handleAcceptMandatoryCookie = () =>{
    axios({
      method : "get",
      withCredentials : true,
      url : `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/token`
    }).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <CookieConsent debug={true} cookieName="force" buttonText="Accept" onAccept={handleAcceptMandatoryCookie}>
        click on accept
      </CookieConsent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My issue is even if I click on accept it keeps show me the cookie consent bar to accept the cookie again. How can I keep it hiding if there is the cookie in my cookies list

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this:
How do you show the `<CookieConsent />` component **only** when `accepted === false`?

First, add a state to your component to handle the status of 'accepted'.

```js
const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted = useState(false)
```

Secondly, only show your component when `isAccepted` is false:

```js
!isAccepted && <CookieConsent .../>
```

Thirdly, toggle the isAccepted inside of your `handleAcceptMandatoryCookie` function:

```js
setIsAccepted(true)
```

Comment: The issue is with react-cookie-consent the bar shouldn't be visible when the cookie exist because when I try without the server side react-cookie-consent create a cookie and when the cookie exist it doesn't show the bar but when I create it with my server side it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `debug={true}` of `<CookieConsent />` props.

From the [docs.](https://github.com/Mastermindzh/react-cookie-consent#debugging-it)